# Is it possible to easily collate recommended system requirements for all owned Steam games?

Tags: steam

I'm looking at getting a laptop and wanted to make sure that most of my Steam games would be compatible. I know how to read hardware requirements but unfortunately I haven't found an easy way to get an overview of hardware requirements for all of the games I own.

Is there a way to see a general list of system requirements based on all of the games in my library? Or am I stuck going through each one and compiling the list myself?

Comment: Unless you're replacing a high-end laptop with a cheap low-end one, the only thing you really have to ensure is that your new laptop has as good or better graphics than your old. If so then your new laptop should run every game you old one could.

Comment: I don't currently own a laptop so that doesn't help me much. And my desktop, even though its old, probably isn't a great benchmark either. Hence the question.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought you were upgrading a laptop. Since you're replacing your desktop you'll also need to ensure your CPU is as fast.

Comment: No problem. I realized after your comment that it probably wasn't very clear.

Comment: How many games are we talking?

Comment: @Schwern Its currently only 35 but the winter sale isn't over yet... So not huge but enough that it would nice if there was a way to get a snapshot of requirements rather than manually going through myself.

Comment: @TZHX or the other voters, care to explain why this is off-topic? I'm not asking for hardware recommendations but rather a way to view a summary of steam game hardware recommendations.

Comment: I have nearly 500. :)  This might be presented as an interesting programming problem on another exchange.  Get a list of your games, scrape the requirements from steampowered.com and assemble them together into a summary.  The first two is straightforward.  The last is complicated.  How do you compare [Graphics: Shader 3.0 / Open GL 3.2+](http://store.steampowered.com/app/233250/) with [Graphics: 256 MB](http://store.steampowered.com/app/245470/)?

Comment: @Schwern Yikes. So my case might be a little on the lazy side then. I had the exact same thought. I might have found a new project to work on.

Comment: Define "requirements." Depending on your target resolution, framerate and framerate/quality tradeoffs you're willing to take the answer for the same one game can vary from a 770 (or less) to SLI'd 980s, for example.

Comment: @badp The requirements I'm looking for is whatever the game manufacturer has set for their game. I know they can differ a lot depending on preferences but that's something I can determine for myself after locating all of the my games requirements. So this question is really aimed at that last part, finding a summary or collection of game requirements for all owned steam games.

Comment: @MatthewGreen then (regardless of whether or not this question is on-topic) I'm afraid you're going to need your favourite language's equivalent of Mechanizer and Beautiful Soup :)

Comment: I don't think he was asking for hardware recommendations. He's asking for where the recommended specs are; which amazingly are at the bottom of the store page. (Above the reviews)

Comment: @aytimothy Except that he isn't asking for that at all. He's asking for a tool that *compiles* that information from across his library of games and spits out some sort of meta-requirement. Which is a very different sort of question.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz, I realised. The point is: It's not off-topic.

Comment: I don't believe it's half as clear cut as you seem to, and the distinction between your original comment and my correction is the crux of why.

Answer (score 1):

You can individually go through and look at the stats and comprise a list. Also, I think there is a website called canirunit.com in which you can type in the name of the game  and you can get recommended specifications there.

Comment: I'm hoping I don't have to do this manually, like I mentioned in my question. But I also realize there may not be a better way. Either way, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not exactly what you want, but you can have a look at the **[Steam Hardware & Software Surveys](http://store.steampowered.com/hwsurvey)** to gauge what *other* people are running on their PCs. You can use this as a rough guide for what works and what doesn't.

For example, the average Intel CPU speed is 2.3-2.69 GHz, with 49% of people running dual cores, 43% Quad core.

As for RAM, most seem to be running 8GB however over December there was a trend up of 2 and 4 GB machines (probably as people got laptops for Christmas).

Like I said, it's only a rough estimate of what other people are running, but if you stick to the averages (or just slightly better than average) you should be able to get a reasonable laptop for most games that you play.